# Google Cloud SDK's authentication not working in ubuntu(gcloud auth)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I tried authenticating gcloud using multiple ways (browser, without browser and service account), but none of them is authenticating. It even didn't throw any error.

I am using the latest version of google cloud sdk.

```
user@ksystem:~$ gcloud version

Google Cloud SDK 404.0.0
alpha 2022.09.23
beta 2022.09.23
bq 2.0.78
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.12
core 2022.09.23
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.14
```

In all methods after verification its not processing next step.

```
user@ksystem:~$ sudo gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser

Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsdk.cloud.google.com%2Fauthcode.html&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fsqlservice.login+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&state=ghhfWirxKhFHr0P0AElEQ4S4ZhyIp2&prompt=consent&access_type=ZLY67jPU&code_challenge_method=S256

Enter authorization code: XvQ5DwgtnsokZYdocjFL95p55DWR
```

Please advice on this, I even tried downgrading the version to 381, but it also not working.

Environment Details:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-pol>
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

When I checked the debugger console from the browser the following API returns 404, all other APIs return success.

```
https://developerprofiles-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/profile?key=AIzaAP-jjEJBzmIyKR4%24unique=gc312
```

Comment: What type of environment are you running this command? Use the browser method, use the browser debugger and look for errors in the Console and Network tab. Edit your post with those details.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the reply, I updated the question with the required information, please have a look.

Comment: I'm using the same OS and gcloud SDK version. Have you tried reinstalling it and running with sudo ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yeah I am running it with sudo also i reinstalled it multiple times

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it